# Edit text file content in ForEach-Object loop

Tags: powershell, loops, scripting

I'm trying to edit a text file from PowerHhell, following the refresh of a directory.

Trying to `Get-Content` from the target location where the source `dbconnecthost` is what we're searching for. 
We then want to replace with the target information and `Set-Content`. These variables are being pulled from another `.ps1` file.

The below is what I'm attempting to use.

```
function ReplaceDBhost {
    Get-Content ("$TargetLocation\Data\config.txt") | Foreach-Object {
        $_ -replace ('^dbconnecthost=' + '$SourceDBConnectHost'), ('dbconnecthost=' + '$TargetDBConnectHost' )
    } | Set-Content  ("$TargetLocation\Data\config.txt")
}
```

The problem is, I'm not getting any changes when I run this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

When you use single-quotes, that's called a string *literal* and does not support *variable expansion*.  To correct this, you need to use double-quotes (or no quotes at all if your variable is a string and you're appending with `+`):

```
(Get-Content -Path "$TargetLocation\Data\config.txt") |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace "^dbconnecthost=$SourceDBConnectHost", "dbconnecthost=$TargetDBConnectHost"
    } |
    Set-Content -Path "$TargetLocation\Data\config.txt"
```

Although your regex can be improved using a lookaround:

```
"(?<=^dbconnecthost=)$SourceDBConnectHost", $TargetDBConnectHost
```

---

Shortened:

```
$path = @{Path = "$TargetLocation\Data\config.txt"}
$pattern = "(?<=^dbconnecthost=)$SourceDBConnectHost"
(Get-Content @path) -replace $pattern, $TargetDBConnectHost | Set-Content @path
```

Comment: @LotPings good catch - or use `-Raw` with the multi-line regex option.